# Database value show in array in html format

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to show database value by replace `$view['time']` value to `%time%` by array.

Example

if `$view['time']='8;00 pm';` when i write `%time%` here show 8:00 pm.

It is working for single raw but when I try to show value by loop here show only first value here is my code please cheek and help me.

```
<?php
$msg='
<div class="pad9">
    <img src="http://trickround.xtgem.com/files/licon.gif"/>
    <a href="%post-id%"> %post-title% </a>
    <br/>
    <div class="lined"> </div> 
    <font color="fuchsia">  </font>
    <font color="red">%time%</font>
</div>
<div class="lines"></div>';

$post1 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id_user = :id order by id DESC LIMIT 10'); 

$post1->execute(array(':id' => '4')); 

while ($view = $post1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $bbcode = array(
        '%post-title%' => htmlentities($view['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        '%post-messge%' => $view['message'],
        '%time%' => $view['time'],
        '%post-id%' => ''.$view['id'].'.html',
        '%post-url%' => ''.$view['url'].'.html'
    );

    $msg = str_replace(array_keys($bbcode), array_values($bbcode), $msg); 
    echo $msg;
}
```

please give solution how I get all fetch value .

Comment: Please rewrite your text and format your code. Saving time for yourself while writing the question and making it harder for us to read it is not the appropriate way to ask a question.

Comment: When writing text, use punctuation and line breaks. When coding, there's no style points for writing everything in one row, rather the opposite. Readability is important. In both cases.

Comment: _"Then I try show result but fail"_ - Fail how? Not replacing the placeholders? Replacing the wrong placeholders? Error messages?

Comment: i edit my question by more clearly please see

Comment: You're changing the original string, so in the next iteration, your placeholders won't exist (they have been with the data from the first iteration). Instead of storing the result of your `str_replace(....)` in the variable `$msg`, echo it straight away: `echo str_replace(...);` and it should work.

Comment: Dear mangus if posible give me an example

Comment: I have voted to reopen because the question is clear enough now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the original string `$msg` on each iteration. After the first iteration, the string `$msg` will contain the data from the first iteration, where all placeholders already have been replaced.

Instead of storing the result in `$msg`, just echo the result directly in your loop.

Change:

```
$msg = str_replace(array_keys($bbcode), array_values($bbcode), $msg); 
echo $msg;
```

to just:

```
echo str_replace(array_keys($bbcode), $bbcode, $msg);
```

As @mickmackusa pointed out, there's no need to use `array_values()` for the second argument since `str_replace()` only uses the array values anyway.

Comment: thanks it work nice

Comment: @Magnus You don't need to call `array_values()`, the keys are ignored.  You might like to vote to reopen now that the question is clarified.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Good point about the `array_values()`. Totally missed that one :-) I've already voted to reopen this question about 9 days ago though.

Comment: Me too.  It says I can't reopen for another 9 days.